# how to create this type of JSON array dynamically

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Hardcoded:

```
    var imageInfoCols = [{
        "location" : "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/42060851/ImageGrid/1.jpg",
        "title" : "Movie 1"
    }, {
        "location" : "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/42060851/ImageGrid/2.jpg",
        "title" : "Movie 2"
    }, {
        "location" : "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/42060851/ImageGrid/3.jpg",
        "title" : "Movie 3"
    }
];
```

Each item has two properties, location and title.

I want to create an object with two properties and push it onto a json array. What is the best way to do this using a for loop?

Cheers

Comment: JSON is a _serialisation format_ for structured data that produces a string.  What you have is a (nested) JS array literal.

Comment: I started writing an answer, but this is so trivial you should be able to figure it out yourself

Comment: `var arr = [{location: 'http...',title:'Movie 1'},{location: 'http...',title:'Movie 2'}, ... ]` Then serialize it with `JSON.stringify()` if you need to.

Comment: You don't need a "JSON Array". JSON is javascript stringified, basically. `var jsonArray = JSON.stringify(imageInfoCols);` gives you that array in JSON.

Comment: If you can't even create an array, what are you going to do with it after, with such a skills? You should learn basics really.

Comment: I am learning - sorry.

Comment: You guys are being rude.

Comment: Yes, this is great, but there are much better ways to learn - there are thousands of useful resources to start with.

Comment: @dfsq - Yes, and when you denigrate instead of providing links to reputable resources, w3school answers get posted and accepted. `:O`

Comment: @JaredFarrish Why rude? I'm just pointing that this is dead end, or at least not effective way to learn new language.

Comment: I know how to create an array with one property, ['yes','no' ...] etc, its when there are multiple properties I get confused

Comment: @user3754111 Here is a useful [resource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array). It will help you to understand arrays. Good luck!

Comment: @user3754111 - See http://jsfiddle.net/7ZrbS/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this will help:

```
var objectArray = [];
var field1 = 'location'; // dynamically set field name
var field2 = 'title'; // do same for second field
var length = 3;

for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    object = {};

    // javascript object properties can be acccessed
    // and set dynamically with index notation
    object[field1] = 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/42060851/ImageGrid/' + i + '.jpg';
    object[field2] = 'Movie ' + i;

    objectArray.push(object);
};
// json is the actual JSON string
var json = JSON.stringify(objectArray);
```

I am dynamically setting the key names, key values and the number of javascript objects. In javascript objects and hash tables are one in the same.

Comment: thank you, i just tried doing it that way, couldn't get it to work - but that clears things up

Comment: I think `object` is a reserved word in Javascript. So `object = {}` will probably throw an error.

Comment: I doubt it, it works for me in Chrome. Prettify (the syntax highlighter used) has its issues, and occasionally mishighlights.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp

JSON just refers to the format the data is sent to the server in.

So just build your array like the link above says then do this:

```
var serializedJson = JSON.stringify(imageInfoCols);
```

Then send serializedJson to your server.

EDIT: It doesn't matter where the data is going I suppose.  JSON is just a method for converting a javascript object to a string that can be more easily stored or transported.

Comment: In general links to w3schools ([see...](http://w3fools.com)) are frowned on. Try something on MDN.